# Переход из menu android на другое Activity

Tags: java, android

Как перейти с пункта меню в Android на другое активити? Загуглил, посоветовали этот код. Но при нажатии на пункт меню, приложение вылетает.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_about:

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: а ошибка какая? мы обычные люди, а не экстрасенсы

Comment: AboutActivity в манифест не забыли добавить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не добавил в Manifest Activity.

```
      <activity
        android:name=".AboutActivity"
        android:label="About Activity"></activity>
```